# when using max() with mysqli, only one field is changing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having problems with the code:

```
   $query="INSERT INTO tripmembers(tripId,id) SELECT MAX(tripId),'id' FROM tripdetails";
   $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

wherein the tripId is getting added,but the id field is not.(tried both with or without the single quotes around 'id')

MY AIM IS TO copy tripId and id from "tripdetails' to 'tripmembers' for the last entry of 'tripmembers'
even this code is not working:

```
$query="INSERT INTO tripmembers(tripId,id) SELECT tripId,id FROM tripdetails WHERE tripId=MAX(tripId)";
```

Iv checked the spellings of all the fields but yet id is being stored as 0 every time in "tripmembers" table ,but has the proper id in "tripdetails" table

PEASE HELP!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Presumably the single quotes around `'id'` are your problem...

Comment: Iv tried even without the the single quotes, yet the id field shows 0

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful.  Which `id` should be returned?  `mysql` allows this behavior, but most databases do not.

Comment: please check the edited question

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes (**`'id'`**) makes that a string literal. If that's being inserted into the `id` column which is a numeric datatype, the literal string will evaluate to zero. Just as if you had specified a literal zero.

If your intent is to reference a column named `id` from the tripdetails table, then remove the single quotes.  If you do that, the value returned for the id column will be indeterminate. The value will be from some row, any row, in the tripdetails table.

I suspect you may want a `GROUP BY id` clause, but that's just a guess. It's not clear what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: i am trying to copy tripId and id from the last entry in tripdetails table to tripmembers 
even this is not working:

   $query="INSERT INTO tripmembers(tripId,id) SELECT tripId,id FROM tripdetails WHERE tripId=MAX(tripId)";

Answer (score 1):

Given your comments and edit, you can use `limit 1` to achieve what you're after:

```
INSERT INTO tripmembers(tripId,id) 
SELECT tripId,id FROM tripdetails ORDER BY tripID DESC LIMIT 1
```